# Interpretation of the 1D transverve field Ising model vacuum state in a spin-language

Tags: condensed-matter, ising-model, lattice-model, spin-chains

The 1D transverse field Ising model, 
\begin{equation}
H=-J\sum_{i}\sigma_i^z\sigma_{i+1}^z-h\sum_{i}\sigma^x_i,
\end{equation}
can be solved via the Jordan-Wigner (JW) transformation (for further reference about the explicit form of the JW transformation, one may look at the following [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation)). Here, $\sigma^z,\sigma^x$ are the Pauli matrices and the sum is carried over an infinite chain (consider $J>0$). After the JW non-local mapping to spinless fermionic operators (and a Bogoliubov transformation), one obtains a quadratic Hamiltonian that is diagonal in momentum space :
\begin{equation}
H=\sum_k \epsilon(k,h)(a^\dagger_ka_k+1/2)
\end{equation}
Where we express $h$ in units of $J$ and $\epsilon(k,h)$ represents the dispersion relation of the excitations of the system and depends on the transverse field $h$ and wave-vector $k$. $a^{(\dagger)}_k$ is the usual annihilation (creation) operator, which annihilates (creates) a spinless fermion with momentum $k$. For $h<1$ this dispersion relation is gapped, meaning that there is a finite energy cost to create $a^\dagger_k$ excitation with respect to the vacuum ground-state $\left|~0\right>$.

Here is my **question** : How do you explicitly write down this $\left|~0\right>$ ground-state in terms of the original $\sigma^z$ basis ? Explicitly : For $h=0$, we know that the ground-state corresponds to all spins up or down, i.e. $\left|~0\right>$=$\left|~\cdots\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\cdots\right>$ or $\left|~0\right>$=$\left|~\cdots\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow\cdots\right>$. Now, how do you find the explicity form of $\left|~0\right>$ for $h\neq0$ ?

Comment: The wave function can be explicitly written as Pfaffians in $\sigma^x$ basis, and then you can formally transform this wave function to $\sigma^z$ basis, and the result won't be explicit, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After thinking about it I must say it is not as simple as I thought it would be. The JW transformation on the transverse Ising model contains quite a few subtleties.

So to proceed,

1) Take your ground state for **ANY** $h$ expressed in the spinless fermion language. I stress **ANY** because this condition is true always - it's not just for $h<1$. Now this is the vacuum, specified by $| 0 \rangle$ s.t. $a_k |0\rangle = 0$. This is a non-trivial condition written in the spin-language, i.e. we take the operators $a_k$, and do the following:

2) Apply the reverse Bogoliubov transform on $a_k$: $\{a_k\}\to \{b_k\}$.

3) Apply an inverse Fourier transform: $\{b_k\} \to \{b_i\}$

4) Apply the inverse Jordan Wigner transformation: $b_i = f(\sigma^x,\sigma^y,\sigma^z)$ .

All these transformations are invertible (see [this pdf for JW and inverse JW transformation](http://michaelnielsen.org/blog/archive/notes/fermions_and_jordan_wigner.pdf)), which is why you can do that. So composing all the maps one can express $a_k = g(\sigma^x, \sigma^y, \sigma^z)$, where $g$ is the highly non-trivial function.

Then one has to find the kernel of $g(\sigma^x, \sigma^y, \sigma^z)$, i.e. $|\psi\rangle $ s.t. $g(\sigma^x, \sigma^y, \sigma^z) |\psi\rangle = 0$. $|\psi \rangle $ is the ground state written in the spin-basis.

You can write a program to do it for you symbolically, but for all your effort what you'll end up with is a highly non-local ground state in the spin-basis because of all the Jordan-Wigner strings.

**Remark:**

There are many subtleties associated with this transformation. What is very often not mentioned when one derives the spectrum $\epsilon(k,h)$ is that the JW transformation MUST be performed separately on states with different parity in the Hilbert space.

This is because the imposition of periodic boundary conditions in spin space implies the imposition of periodic boundary conditions for ODD number of fermions but anti-periodic boundary conditions for EVEN number of fermions. This affects the Fourier transform. In the calculation of any macroscopic quantity in the thermodynamic limit, there is no difference, and many books/resources just discard talking about the two cases. But this distinction must be made if one wants to be careful about it.

One question that arose to me when I was thinking about this problem was: hm, in one limit, $h\to\infty$, the ground states is unique, while in the other limit $h \to 0$ the ground states is 2-fold degenerate. Can I see that in the fermion language easily?

There are two resolutions I can think to the problem.

1) It could be that the ground state $|0\rangle_k$ for each $k$ is not unique. That is, instead of the irreducible 2-dimension representation of the fermionic CAR that we usually assume $a_k$ acts in, $a_k$ could be operators in a $2 \times d$ (reducible) dimensional representation, with $d$ 'ground states'.

2) The even and odd sectors of the full Hilbert space give rise to two conditions on the ground state: $a_k$ in the even sector gives a condition $g(\sigma^x, \sigma^y, \sigma^z) |\psi \rangle = 0$ while $a_k$ in the odd sector gives another condition $g'(\sigma^x, \sigma^y, \sigma^z)|\psi'\rangle$ = 0.

It could perhaps be the case that when $h\to \infty$, $|\psi\rangle = |\psi'\rangle$, while when $h \to 0$, $|\psi\rangle \neq |\psi'\rangle$.

It would seem more likely to me that 2) is the correct analysis, though it's going to be one tough assertion to prove.

Comment: I thought of this before and this is most likely the way to go. However, there was two things that I didn't understand how to do : First : how do you invert JW transformation (I have not seen a fermionic variables to spin variables in the references I looked at) ? Second :in our problem, the ground-state for $h<1$ is the vacuum state, i.e. you do not fill anything. Thus how do you find what this corresponds to ? I guess my question is, what is the vacuum state in terms of a spin basis (is it simply not possible to write down and one must use perturbation theory to understand what's going on) ?

Comment: Also note that since your Hilbert space $2^N$ dimensional, a general state could have just as many terms. So even for small $N$, your ground state could look very terrible and have lots of terms. I say this since it's often a misconception when doing many spins that a state is decomposable or has a simple form where some spins are up and others are down. If you really are bent on it, I'd try working it out explicitly for some low dimensional cases like $N = 2$, $3$ etc, in which case you could just write out a matrix for the Hamiltonian and use a computer to find your ground state....

Comment: ... and if you get to that, do post it here as an answer, as I'd also be curious to see what it looks like. If you have any questions about this particular process, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce Check out this set of notes: http://michaelnielsen.org/blog/archive/notes/fermions_and_jordan_wigner.pdf equations 31-34 where the JW transformation and its inverse are presented. I have also updated my answer to address your second question.

Comment: I think your answer is everything I was looking for and is most likely the only way to go. Could you add the link of your last comment in your answer (I think it would just make it better) ? My initial motivation for this question was to try to understand the ground-state of this system via non-perturbative method (here we have the exact solution !). But as you have noted, the answer is something quite involved...

Comment: In order to understand the type of excitations, one must resort to some perturbation theory picture. Then, it is clear that in the thermodynamic limit and for $h<<1$, the lowest energy excitations are highly non-local and correspond to domain walls. However, what happens when you have $h\rightarrow1$ and you get a phase transition ? It seems that the perturbation theory breaks down and the vacuum-state becomes highly mixed with excited states. Then it becomes quite hard to get a real-space spin picture of what is going on...

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce As far as getting the ground state and excited states (and in fact the entire Hilbert space) is concerned, the Jordan Wigner transformation gives you an EXACT result. That's what it means to SOLVE the model exactly. There is no need to resort to perturbation theory. Once again, for ANY $h$, the ground state in the fermion language is $|0\rangle$, while the first excited state is $a_0^\dagger |0\rangle$. That's because the dispersion relation has a minimum at 0 and so putting a fermion at $k=0$ gives the lowest excitation above $|0\rangle$.

Comment: (cont.) Translating the first excited state in terms of the spin language will be a pain but you just follow the same recipe i outlined in my answer. This holds even at $h=1$, criticality. Please try to get this point!! The perturbation theory you are talking about is the approach when you start from either limit $h = 0$ or $h = \infty$ and try to work towards $h=1$. And what you mean by the 'vacuum-state becomes highly mixed with excited states' is that the vacuum state in one of those limits (all spins right for e.g.) gets mixed with the excited states of the corresponding limits (domain

Comment: (cont.) walls etc.) BUT! That's a separate approach from the JW transformation altogether. To draw an analogy, let's say you are in a car and you want to find out the speed at which you are moving. You have an exact solution: simply look at the speedometer. But there's an approximate way to do it: take your stop watch, measure the time between trees you pass on your way, estimate the distance of your trees, to find your approximate speed. But why do that when you can just look at your speedometer??? For the case of the transverse Ising model, the JW transformation very nicely gives you a

Comment: (cont.) speedometer. But not all cars (read: models) have speedometers that can be found easily or at all, which is why we have to resort to estimating the speed by looking at the distance/time between the trees (read: perturbation theory). The 1D transverse Ising model is special in that it is an exactly solvable model.

Comment: I understand that. My initial motivation as I mentioned in my earlier comment is that I'm trying to make sense of the vacuum state in terms of a real-space spin picture. Of course, the exact solution gives you this state but is it highly none trivial. If you want to understand this state in simple terms, you have to resort to perturbation theory. In that sense, the interpretation of your vacuum state comes from a perturbation theory type of argument. From the exact solution you can say (only through a very complicated calculation) what type of vacuum state you have.

Comment: (cont.) but it's just very hard to do ...

Comment: The Bogoliubov transformation has trickier subtleties and they are mentioned even less frequently. In particular, they hold the key to why the ground state has different degeneracy in the strong/weak field limit. I recently posted and answered [a related question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118489/). Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce To find the eigenstates in spin basis exactly, you must also take into account that the fermion vacuum is changed nontrivially after the Bogoliubov transformation. You can find more details in my recent question (and its references) [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118489/). However, IMO, it is in general not helpful to look at a strongly-interacting quantum many-body system in its "original" degrees of freedom (in this case, spin). It makes much more sense to think about quasi-particles (if possible) or the effective theory (in this case, fermions).

Comment: @Chenfeng : Thanks Chenfeng, I will have a look at your recent question. Also, I do agree that looking at the the ground-state in the original or say trivial basis is not so useful indeed. One can really make sense of that vacuum only in the perturbative limit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bottom line is that everyone believes that the inversion of the Jordan-Wigner operation must be able to produce the simple eigenstates that one obtains very easily at either $h \rightarrow 0$ or $h \rightarrow \infty$, but having gone very thoroughly through the literature, it appears that no one has explicitly computed this.

A priori there's no reason why there would be any inconsistency, and the method outlined in nervxxx's answer is certainly expected to work, but it has never been actually done before.